# Blank video on Magento static blocks

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, iframe, video

I'm trying to put a video inside a static block that will appear as a slide in homepage. Every video I try to insert comes out blank. The video uploads correctly, I've tried mp4 and flv video, but nothing. I'd like to avoid using youtube or vimeo iframe.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You will need video player to run the video, have you looked into this https://www.apptha.com/category/extension/magento/hd-flv-player-magento

Comment: So basic Magento (I have 1.9.2.2) doesn't have any video player integrated?

Comment: No it is not...

Answer (score 1):

You will need video player to run the video, have you looked into this https://www.apptha.com/category/extension/magento/hd-flv-player-magento

And you can use this http://magento-flv-player.soft112.com/

I didn't use it myself but you free to give it a try